# How do I parse a polyline metafile record out of a byte array?

Tags: c#, metafile

I need a little help in defining the following Windows GDI type in C#. I have the data in the form of a `byte[]` in C#, and I need to somehow marshal or cast it as the following in C#. I suppose I need to define the proper struct? This is the type:

#### NAME

```
META_POLYLINE
```

#### NEAREST API CALL

```
#include <windows.h>
BOOL32 Polyline
(
    HDC32 hdc,
    const POINT32 *pt,
    INT32 count
);
```

#### DESCRIPTION

```
    U16 array no                Value
    --------------------------- --------------
    0                           no of points
    1 each odd until the end    x of the point
    2 each even until the end   y of the point
```

A polyline is a list of points.  Unlike a polygon, a polyline is always unfilled, and can be open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] buffer;
fixed (byte* b = buffer)
{
   ushort* ptr = (ushort*)b;
   int count = (int)*ptr;
   var points = new Point[count];
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
       int x = (int)*(++ptr);
       int y = (int)*(++ptr);
       points[i] = new Point(x, y);
   }
}
```

*(Untested)*

Comment: Thank you all. Would I be correct to assume that in my Graphics.EnumerateMetafileProc delegate, the data parameter is the actual GDI object (in this case the Polyline)?

Comment: I just tested the code above and it worked like a charm. May I ask one more? How do I convert a WmfPolygon to c#?

Comment: Got Polygon, thanks for the intro. Having trouble with this question if you have a moment please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774291/how-do-i-parse-a-createpenindirect-metafile-record-out-of-a-byte-array

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Polyline entry on PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/Polyline.html) yet?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a metafile record for a polyline... You might want to try doing a [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) from the byte array to a `UInt16` array.