# How do I parse a CREATEPENINDIRECT metafile record out of a byte array?

Tags: c#, metafile

I need a little help in defining the following Windows GDI type in C#. I have the data in the form of a `byte[]` in C#, and I need to somehow marshal or cast it as the following in C#. Please see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773953), as I got the answer to the Polyline. This is the type:

#### NAME

```
META_CREATEPENINDIRECT
```

#### NEAREST API CALL

```
#include <windows.h>
HPEN32 CreatePenIndirect(const LOGPEN32 *pen);

typedef struct tagLOGPEN
{
    UINT        lopnStyle;
    POINT       lopnWidth;
    COLORREF    lopnColor;
} LOGPEN;
```

#### DESCRIPTION

```
U16     Value
0       lopnStyle
1       lopnWidth
2, 3    lopnColor
```

> lopnColor is the color of the pen, lopnWidth is the width of the pen, if the pen's width is > 1 but the lopnStyle is not solid, then lopnStyle is ignored and set to solid anyway.
>
> lopnStyle can be one of `PS_SOLID`, `PS_DASH`, `PS_DOT`, `PS_DASHDOT`, `PS_DASHDOTDOT`, `PS_NULL`, `PS_INSIDEFRAME`, `PS_USERSTYLE`, `PS_ALTERNATE`. Check out the source for that they actually mean.
>
> Theres also a set of flags and masks that can be found in lopnStyle as well that set the end and join styles of lines drawn with a pen, they are `PS_STYLE_MASK`, `PS_ENDCAP_ROUND`, `PS_ENDCAP_SQUARE`, `PS_ENDCAP_FLAT`, `PS_ENDCAP_MASK`, `PS_JOIN_ROUND`, `PS_JOIN_BEVEL`, `PS_JOIN_MITER`, `PS_JOIN_MASK`, `PS_COSMETIC`, `PS_GEOMETRIC`, `PS_TYPE_MASK`, again check out the source to figure these out.

---

Update: This is as close as I can get so far:

```
fixed (byte* b = dataArray)
{
    byte* ptr = (byte*)b;
    // Get style
    l_nStyle = (ushort)*(ptr);
    ++ptr;
    // Get width
    l_nWidth = (ushort)*(++ptr);
    ++ptr;
    // skip one ushort
    ++ptr; ++ptr;
    // Get RGB colors
    l_nColorR = (ushort)*(++ptr);
    l_nColorG = (ushort)*(++ptr);
    l_nColorB = (ushort)*(++ptr);
}
```

Comment: I found this bit of code in Java, it would help if I knew java:
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/PDF/pdf-itext/com/lowagie/text/pdf/codec/wmf/MetaPen.java.htm
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/PDF/pdf-itext/com/lowagie/text/pdf/codec/wmf/InputMeta.java.htm

Comment: I have gotten this far. This does not throw any errors, but the resultant data is not correct:

                ushort l_nStyle; // PS_SOLID == 0
                ushort l_nWidth; // 
                uint l_nColor;

                unsafe
                {
                    fixed (byte* b = dataArray)
                    {
                        ushort* ptr = (ushort*)b;
                        l_nStyle = (ushort)*(++ptr);
                        l_nWidth = (ushort)*(++ptr);
                        l_nColor = (uint)*(++ptr);
                    }
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] buffer;
int style = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 0);
int width = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 2);
var color = Color.FromArgb(buffer[4], buffer[5], buffer[6]);
var pen   = new Pen(color, width)
{
    DashStyle = ..., // set style
    StartCap = ...,
    EndCap = ...
};
```

*(Untested)*

Comment: That is very close. The raw data array contents look like this:[0] 0 byte
  [1] 0 byte
  [2] 0 byte
  [3] 255 byte
  [4] 255 byte
  [5] 0 byte
  [6] 0 byte
  [7] 0 byte

So I used: int l_nColorR = BitConverter.ToUInt16(dataArray, 2);
                int l_nColorG = BitConverter.ToUInt16(dataArray, 3);
                int l_nColorB = BitConverter.ToUInt16(dataArray, 4);
                Color color = Color.FromArgb(l_nColorR,
                                            l_nColorG,
                                            l_nColorB);

Wich is not correct. How do I get an Int from a single Byte?

Comment: If you have a byte array, just get the element at the index. It's already a byte, no need to convert it :-)

Comment: Are you sure it's just 8 bytes? The Java code you linked and the MSDN docs say different. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc250423.aspx

Comment: Perfect. I did 10 more, and got stuck on PolyPolygon16 in EMF. Would you please take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778938/how-do-i-parse-a-polypolygon16-metafile-record-out-of-a-byte-c
Thank you